# Sorting an observablearray contained within an observablearray

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to sort observable arrays.

This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/485/ works nicely with a single observablearray. (Click list items to sort)

But this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/488/ doesn't work. It's an observablearray containing two objects, each of which contain an observablearray that needs sorting.

I'm aware that this line is wrong: `self.FiveFave.FItemGroup.sort(descSort);` I think I might need to use `event.currenttarget` but not sure how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to do something like this you should pass current reference for sorting .

**View:**

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: $parent.headers">
        <li data-bind="click: function(data,event){ $root.sorter($parent,data,event)}, text: title"></li>
    </ul>
```

**View Model:**

```
 self.sorter = function(data,header, event){
        self.activeSort = header;
        var prop = self.activeSort.sortPropertyName;
        var descSort = function(a,b){ 
            return a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
        data.FItemGroup.sort(descSort);
    };
```

Working Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/00wz84de/)

Most **important** thing here is you should declare

`self.FItemGroup = ko.observableArray(fItemGroup);` not as `self.FItemGroup = fItemGroup;`

if you dont do something like that means you are simply inviting a dependency . Guess what happens next if you try to sort first loop data second loop data will also be sorted . Caution advised .